# How to get a proper error stack while designing application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Before, I used `async.js` with callbacks to make a webapp. It worked very nicely -- when an error would occur, I'd get the whole stack pointing exactly to the line where the error happened.

Now, when I'm trying the same with `async/await` in Node's harmony mode, the errors only point to the last catch blocks. Example:

```
try {
  await goDoSomething();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Now, `goDoSomething` will do some async action, like pull from database, and then a bunch of synchronous code, like process the records, etc.

If an error happens in that synchronous code that processes records, the stack will point to the catch block of the code above (and not the actual line where the error happened).

This is insanely difficult to debug. Which leaves me with the assumption that I should have these `try/catch` blocks multiple times throughout all of my code (even synchronous stuff)...?

What am I missing? How do I have normal and accurate error catching with `async/await`?

Comment: You tried using `console.log(err.stack)`?

Comment: @JohnVandivier, I've tried it all at this point, still no luck. That example above is just a sample to show what I'm doing. I'm more interested in application design at this point (how to catch proper errors) & how others do it, rather than actual code / libraries...

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages to get an async stack trace. I'd recommend [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) based on Github stars.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you want in nodejs. I spent several days trying different approaches, stack size settings and libraries like longjohn. When you work with external datasources, top of produced stack always something like `pgDriver.onPackedReceived...`. And reason for this, is that it is about EVENTS, not about sync/async. Async stacktraces works fine without any libraries. But not events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, you're saying the way everyone does it is they have errors that point to nowhere -- as in the last catch block and beyond that you're on your own?

Comment: I don't know how everybody does it. But suggest your right, unless somebody will give better answer.